# Cannot read VARCHAR columns with RHive

Tags: r, hive

Trying to read a table with RHive.

```
rhive.load.table("tablename")
```

Everything works fine for numeric columns. If they are VARCHAR, they are returned as numeric columns with NA as their value. Data in the table (if accessed directly) is OK.

Any hints?

Comment: In the [RHive documentation](https://www.slideshare.net/SeonghakHong/rhive-tutorials-basic-functions) they say the function is similar to `df1 <- rhive.query("SELECT * FROM myTable")` . Does it do the same thing? _i.e._ does not load VARCHAR data. Also, what is the current max length of your VARCHAR variable in the database ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have tried both. They do the same. Curiously enough, changing the type from Varchar to  String made the whole thing work properly. I can't say that I understand why.